# How do I put integer type in if?

Tags: python

Everytime I write in my input string or integer it just gives me `Input must be a number!`, even if it is a integer type. Can someone tell me what I did wrong or what I could do to make this work.

````
    
temperatur1=input("Temperatur in " + erste_einheit + ": ")
        if temperatur1 != type(int):
            print("Input must be a number!")
        if temperatur1 == type(int):
            pass```
````

Comment: Check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-numbers

Answer (score 0):

```
temperatur1 = input("Temperatur in " + erste_einheit + ": ")
if not temperatur1.isdigit():
    print("Input must be a number!")
else:
    temperatur1 = int(temperatur1)
```